# Regex match end_of_line/newline difference in C# and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I wrote a parser for a custom (subset of) `BBCode` in `Javascript` and now I translated it to `C#`. This custom `BBCode` allows parsing line by line so I have `regex` allowing me to "pop" the first line from the `BBCode` string:

`/(^.*$|^.*\r?\n)/`

It matches an empty string. The first part `^.*$` matches a simple string like `"Simple string"` (single line without `CrLf` at the end).
The second part `^.*\r?\n` matches the first line ending with `CrLf`.

This works perfect in `Javascript`. But while running the unit tests in `C#` I noticed a difference.

Assume we have `"line1\n"` as input.

---

The `regex` in `Javascript` will match it as follows:

`^.*$` won't match because `.` is any symbol except `CrLf` and we have `\n` at the end.

`^.*\r?\n` will match as we have string starting with 0 or more symbols and `\n` at the end.

---

Now in `C#` it works different:

`^.*$` will match (why?), but only the `line1`. Thus the whole `/(^.*$|^.*\r?\n)/` will also match only `line1` an the `\n` goes missing.

---

Could someone please explain? Is there a way to force `C# regex` to behave like the `Javascript regex` in the sense described above?

The simplest workaround would be to change the order in the pattern : `/(^.*$|^.*\r?\n)/` -> `/(^.*\r?\n|^.*$)/` and so the problem will be solved ...,

but I still would like to know the reason behind that difference.

Click [here for the `C#` test code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0Kfev) ...

For `Javascript` see below:

```js
const first_line_pattern = /(^.*$|^.*\r?\n)/
const single_string_pattern = /^.*$/
const line_pattern = /^.*\r?\n/

const input4 = "line1\n"

function log(pattern) {
  let m4 = input4.match(pattern)
  console.log('~~~~~~~~' + pattern.toString() + '~~~~~~~~~')
  console.log("'line1\\n':':" + (m4 != null) + ":value: /" + (m4 ? m4[0] : 'no match') + "/")
}

log(first_line_pattern)
log(single_string_pattern)
log(line_pattern)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Use `\z` to match the very end of string in C#

Comment: The `.` in C# matches any char but LF (by default), so `.` in JS is roughly `[^\n\r]` in C#.

Comment: `.` didn't cause any problem in my case. I didn't know that `\z` is the right substitute for `$` in Javascript. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is fine, I just wanted you to also understand that part. `.` and anchors behavior is interconnected. `/(^.*$|^.*\r?\n)/` works for you in JS, right? And you want to have the same in C#? Since `$` is not working the same and `.` is not the same, you know you need `@"^[^\r\n]*\z|^[^\r\n]*\r?\n"` in C#.

Comment: wait. In Javascript `.` matches any single character except line terminators: \n, \r so what is the difference to C#. Could you give an example?

Comment: See my second comment. `.` in C# is `[^\n]`. In JS, it is `[^\r\n]`. And there are no flags or options that could redefine this behavior.

Comment: oh, OK I see now. So if one uses `/(^.*\z|^.*\r?\n)/` the difference would be only that C# would match something like `"\r"`, whereas Javascript will not. Or `"'\r\r\n"` will also be matched in C# , but not in Javascript ...
Thank you!